# How do you say “I’m interested in doing sth.” and “I’m interested to do sth.” ?

Tags: constructions

I’m trying to figure out how to say

**(1)** “I’m interested to do sth.”

and

**(2)** “I’m interested in doing sth.”

---

**(1)** So in Collins dictionary, we have the example

« Je serais intéressé de connaître votre opinion. » = “I would be interested to hear your views.” *(Please see screenshot below).*

So from this example, I’m guessing that « Je suis intéressé de faire qch » equals “I’m interested to do something”. Is this **grammatically** correct?

**(2)** I would also like to know how to say “I’m interested in doing something.” Google Translate is saying the answer is « Je suis intéressé à faire quelque chose. » Is Google’s Translation **grammatically** correct?

I would just like to know if they are grammatically correct translations. :) Also, I’m a beginner so if you do decide to give an explanation, please make it as simple as possible. Thank you so much! :)

---

**(1)**: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/interested
[image]

**(2)**[image]

Comment: What do you think the difference between *interested in* and *interested to* is in English? For me, *"I'm interested to do something"* isn't idiomatic in English; I would say *"I'm interested in doing something."* (Although I might say *"I'm interested to know something"*.) I think this has to do with the fact that *know* is a stative verb and *do* is an action verb.

Comment: Yes, please provide concrete examples of the English sentences you are thinking about with an explanation of their meaning.

Comment: Fyi, the everyday expression in English: I'm interested in doing x in French is: Cela m'intéresse de faire x. That is how people actually speak. [je suis intéressé à] [**BUZZER**], Je me suis intéressée à/áu [x] etc.. Yes, for: I became interested in x. etc. The French do not really use je suis intéressé à and de in colloquial French.

Answer (score 2):

A) **I'm interested in** reading. [everyday language]

Two main ways to express that in French use the s'intéresser form of the verb rather than the être intéressé form:

1. La lecture m'intéresse.
   OR
2. Je m'intéresse à la lecture.
   OR
3. Je suis intéressée **par** la lecture. [possible, yes.]

B) **I'd be interested to hear your views**. [you can also use the present, am interested]

1. Je serais intéressée de connaître ton opinion. [from the Collins Dictionary]
   OR
2. Cela m'intéresserait de connaître ton opinion.
   OR
3. Connaître ton opinion m'intéresserait.

French uses the pronomial forms of the verb s'intéresser (Je m'intéresse, tu t'intéresses) much more than être intéressé (conjugating the verb être and using the past participle) for the examples you have provided, though, I warn you, this can get very tricky.

Basically, 1) to be interested in x = s'intéresser à; to be interested to see or hear etc. s'intéresser, also. Or you reverse the sentence in French and put the object first: La lecture m'intéresse.

So, basically 1) s'intéresser à is the same thing as 2) être intéressé par. But everyone uses 1), generally. It is difficult to define why, but there must be a reason.

- Je m'intéresse à la musique.
- La musique m'intéresse.
- Je suis intéressé par la musique.

Please note: Generally, when using the form **être intéressé**, you have to use **par**.
[This is just an introductory idea. I have not covered every possible angle.]

interested to [hear, know, verb] has to be a stative verb, not an action verb.

Comment: If I can give a lead, and maybe my native point of view on the reason why "je m'intéresse" is very used, I think it's because it conveys an idea of continuity and it gives a more "active" vibe. For instance, I would use it to say something like "At the moment, I'm interested in game dev, so I've been watching a lot of tutorials about it". I would use "Je suis intéressé par [...]" with a more general, passive point of view -> "I'm interested in history in general" (I like to hear stories about the past, but I'm not doing a lot to know more about it).

Comment: "je m'intéresse à x" donne une idée de continuité? Je ne suis pas convaincue.

Comment: C'est l'intérêt des commentaires : je propose une piste pour expliquer le "pourquoi" que vous posez lorsque vous dites "there must be a reason".
J'ai édité la 2e partie désobligeante de votre commentaire.
Pour revenir au fond, comme je le disais, "je m'intéresse" donne l'idée que le locuteur est actif, effectue des actions associées au sujet auquel il s'intéresse. J'aurais donc tendance à l'utiliser lorsque je veux insister sur le fait que le sujet m'intéresse réellement et pas uniquement de façon vague, abstraite.
Peut-être que mon idée de "continuité" était une erreur, j'en conviens.